# Facebook event subscribe override callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

What happen when initially, the event subscribe was declared this way.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  alert('you have liked me!');
});
```

However, later on we would like to change the response,

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  callSomeOtherFunction();
});
```

Will this override the callback of the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you want to override the callback function, you should use [FB.Event.unsubscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.unsubscribe/) .

Subscribing event again binds multiful event handlers, so both functions will be excuted.

Comment: Cool~ so subscribing is binding the callback event handlers? do u have the information for this? I would like to read about it.